# Зачем нужен указатель на абстрактный класс?

Tags: c++, классы, указатели, наследование

Не понимаю до конца суть проблемы. Посоветуйте как понять?

### Мое текущее понимание понятие "Абстрактный класс":

Абстрактный класс нужен для того, чтобы запретить создавать экземпляры того, что нельзя материализовать. Например, есть понятие "Слово". Это абстрактное понятие. Уточнение некоторых характеристик понятия "Слово" можно уже материализовывать.

### Например:

```
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class word {
public:
    std::string _meaning;

    word() { _meaning = ""; }
    virtual void show() = 0;
};

class english_word : public word {
public:
    english_word() : word() { };
    english_word(std::string meaning) { _meaning = meaning; }

    virtual void show() override {
        std::cout << _meaning << std::endl;
    }
};


int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");


    word *wrd;
    english_word ewrd("Hello");

    wrd = &ewrd; // 1
    wrd->show();

    ewrd.show(); // 2

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

### Проблема:

Сплошь и рядом при описании полиморфизма, натыкаюсь на то, что "ссылку на класс потомок можно присвоить в указатель на базовый класс". Но зачем ? Так же сложнее.. Зачем делать //1 если можно сразу сделать //2 ? Объясните или посоветуйте где про это почитать можно?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вот вам простой пример, прямо из вашей иерархии. Но сначало небольшое отступление.

У вас базовый класс word задает некое понятие, или по-другому абстрагирует некую сущность. То есть тип word задает некое самое общее поведение (общий смысл) для всевозможных слов в рамках вашей задачи. Кроме того, в рамках вашей же задачи есть особенности для слов из разных языков мира и поэтому, в частности, вы создаете другой тип **уточняющий** описание/поведение слов, а именно слов Английского языка (class english_word).

Наследование, это специфицирование (уточнение, или изменение) поведения некоей базового понятия/сущности.

Полиморфизм идет с наследованием рука об руку. Он позволяет иметь механизм работы с объектами общего типа, или общего поведения (то есть, общего набора функций, или интерефейса).

Мы можем создать общий механизм работы со всеми типами-наследниками типа word. **Ключевой момент - общий механизм работы!**

Пример. Базовый класс word имеет метод show(), характерный для всей иерархии ваших классов (в рамках вами принятой абстракции). Этот метод подразумевает, что в наследниках показ слова будет каким-то образом различен для разных языков мира.

Допустим, что у вас есть некий механизм, который позволяет сделать вызов этого метода, независимо от того, какой именно тип слова (какого языка) ему передается. То есть, данный механизм будет реализовывать полиморфность, заложенную в ваш абстрактный класс word.

Где-то, на просторах вашей программы есть место которое вызывает метод show у любого word, и этому месту **безразлично для какого именно типа** word оно это делает (ему не нужно знать конкретный тип, ему интересен только интерфейс, то есть объявленное поведение):

```
void some_place_in_your_code(word* _a_word)
{
    _a_word->show();
}
```

Теперь мы можем передать в этот метод любой объект, любого наследника типа word и неважно существует этот тип на данный момент, или будет создан в будущем - поведение метода some_place_in_your_code не изменится.

```
some_place_in_your_code( new russian_word() );
some_place_in_your_code( new english_word() );

//... 
some_place_in_your_code( new rohirric_word() ); 
//... 

some_place_in_your_code( new lingua_incognita_word() );
```